# How do I convert this to precise columns and rows?

Tags: row, python-3.3

having a hard time converting to neat columns and rows. Can anyone help?

I have been trying to set columns and rows to 0 and work from there but I cant figure it out.
I just dont know where to insert the information.

n = 5

rate = 0.05

for n in range(0, 3):

```
principal = 10000

for n in range (0,6):

    principal <= 15000

    simple = principal *  (1 + rate * n)

    compound = principal * (1 + rate)**n

    ratea = rate * 100

    ratea = int(ratea)

    principal = int(principal)

    print((ratea),"% $",principal," $","{:.2f}".format(simple)," $","{:.2f}".format(compound))

    principal = principal + 1000

rate = rate + 0.05
```

Comment: what does `rate < 0.02` accomplish?

Comment: whoops supposed to be rate < 0.05 this is still a work in progress

Comment: Even so, the statement doesn't *do* anything

Comment: im still working on this program like I said before, just trying to figure out how to insert columns and rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `string` method `format`.

Comment: in my print statement? how do i go about formatting to a certain decimal place in the compound and simple inputs?

Comment: im trying to do monetary amounts for the last two with two decimal points